# Why won't Active Admin sort this association column properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, activeadmin

Having a pain getting active admin to sort an associated child column.  I have a Profile which has a related "user".

```
ActiveAdmin.register Profile, as: "Member" do

def scoped_collection
  end_of_association_chain.includes(:user)
end

column "Referral", sortable: 'user.referrals' do |member|
  member.user.referrals
end

--error when sorting---

PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ... "users"."id" = "profiles"."user_id" ORDER BY user.referrals...
                                                         ^
: SELECT  "profiles"."id" AS t0_r0, "profiles"."actor_id" AS t0_r1,
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is giving the SQL error because the table "user" doesn't exist (the expected table is probably "users", plural).

You'll want to use the following sortable option:

```rb
# Note sortable is using the plural form of users.
column "Referral", sortable: 'users.referrals' do |member|
  member.user.referrals
end
```

When sorting on a joined table's column it takes the form `"table_name.column"`.